# Wordpress loop problem: Multiple loops, index.php and is_paged causing duplicate posts on next page

Tags: query-posts, loop, pagination, customization, paged

I'm not sure if what I'm experiencing is a result of a bug (due to the recent upgrade to 3.1.2) or poor coding. Ever since I upgraded to version 3.1.2 I've been experiencing a problem with two loops on my index page.

Here's what I've got for my index page:

```
<?php
    if ( ! is_paged() && is_front_page() ) {

    echo '<h6 class="sec1 title">FEATURE</h6>';
    $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );

         if ( isset( $sticky[0] ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 3,
                'post__in'  => $sticky,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1);

            $featured_query = new WP_query( $args );
            while ($featured_query->have_posts() ) :
            $featured_query->the_post();

            get_template_part( 'content', 'featured' );

            endwhile;
        } // endif sticky
    } // endif is_paged
    ?>

    <?php
        $sticky = get_option( 'sticky_posts' );
        echo '<h6 class="sec1 title">LATEST ARTICLES</h6>';
        $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
        $query_args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 10,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'post__not_in' => $sticky
            );

        query_posts($query_args);
        if (have_posts() ) :
        while (have_posts() ) :
        the_post();

        get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
    ?>

    <!--<?php trackback_rdf(); ?>-->

    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

    <div class="box">
        <p>
            <?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?>
        </p>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>

// Navigation comes over here
```

Say for example the first loop *(sticky posts)* - which IS NOT paged, yields **3 posts**, and the second loop *(all other posts)* - which IS paged, yields **10 posts**. The problem I'm experiencing is that when I move to the next page, the last **3 posts** from the second loop on page 1 get repeated at the the top of page 2.

---

Note: The first loop is only on page 1, and doesn't get repeated on the second page, which is what I intended.

Note 2: I assume that the second loop is considering - in some odd way, the posts from the first loop as one of its own. But it still shows 10 posts on the first page + 3 posts from the first loop.

---

So in essence its:

**PAGE 1:**

Loop 1: 3 posts (3 unique posts)

Loop 2: 10 posts (10 unique posts)

**PAGE 2:**

Loop 1: Doesn't execute - as intended, due to `( ! is_paged() )`

Loop 2: 10 posts (7 unique, 3 duplicated from the last 3 (from the second loop) on the first page)

So this is what I tried: I removed the `( ! is_paged() && is_front_page )` condition along with the entire first loop, and the problem got resolved.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you revert back to when it was working and try update manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried reverting back to the older version 3.0.x, but the problem remained the same.

The answer can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843214/wordpress-loop-problem-multiple-loops-index-php-and-is-paged-causing-duplicate/5853514#5853514